# TypeError: must be a str, and not type

Tags: python

I am pretty new to Python but have the following code which is returning an error:

```
        process = subprocess.Popen(GBPath + ' --record'+ DEVICES[0] + ' ' + APP + ' ' + EMAIL, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        process.wait()
```

The error returned is

> TypeError: must be a str, and not type

For some additional context Devices[0] returns a number, the rest of it is all predefined values

I have solved a lot of errors and this is the only one I cant figure out!

Comment: `str(DEVICES[0])`

Comment: GBPath (is a pre-defined) directory path

Comment: Tried str(Devices[0]) and same error

Comment: You have a bug in the code that is assigning these variables. You could do `print([repr(p) for p in [GBPath, DEVICES[0], APP, EMAIL]])` to see which one has gone bad.

Comment: It may be more clear to compose the string as `'{} --record {} {} {}'.format(GBPath, DEVICES[0], APP, EMAIL)` or better yet, don't build a shell command at all: `Popen([GBPath, '--record', DEVICES[0], APP, EMAIL],  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: Yep that got it